# opening an URL in safari while iPhone button is clicked

Tags: iphone

I want to add a button to my iPhone application which will open an URL in safari on iPhone when clicked (my application will terminate right?)

Thanks.

Raihan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url` in `UIApplication`.

`UIApplication` is a singleton, so your code would look something like this:

```
NSURL *url;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your app will close if you are simply opening in Safari.

You can, however, use a WebView control to embed the web browser in your app.  This way your app will not terminate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the application needs to be in that way. Could you let me know what API I need to call so that the URL is opened in safari and my application is closed?